# Dynamically change script src client-side

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an HTML page which contains:

- a `<select>` dropdown with 3 options with an `onchange` event to a JS function
- a DIV holder with a script element inside:

Here's the code:

```
<select onChange="getData(this.value);">
    <option value="-">Limba/Language</option>
    <option value="ro">Romana</option>
    <option value="en">Engleza</option>
</select>
<div id="output">
    <script id="widget" type="text/javascript" src="js1.js"></script>
</div>
```

And here's the JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getData(title)
{
    switch(title)
    {
        case "ro":
            var s = document.createElement("script");
                s.type = "text/javascript";
                s.src = "js1.js";
                s.innerHTML = null;
                s.id = "widget";
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = s;
        break;
        case "en":
            var s = document.createElement("script");
                s.type = "text/javascript";
                s.src = "js2.js";
                s.innerHTML = null;
                s.id = "widget";
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = s;
        break;
        default:
        void(0);
    }
}
</script>
```

When I select option 2 or 3 I get this output in my browser: `[object HTMLScriptElement]`

What I want to do is switch the src property of the script tag based on the value selected in the dropdown element.
I want to do this client-side and preferably without any external libraries...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other solution is great :)
...but if you still want to create elements via JavaScript you should use appendChild instead of innerHTML...

Here is what your JavaScript should be :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getData(title)
{
    switch(title)
    {
        case "ro":
            var s = document.createElement("script");
                s.type = "text/javascript";
                s.src = "js1.js";
                s.innerHTML = null;
                s.id = "widget";
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("output").appendChild(s);
        break;
        case "en":
            var s = document.createElement("script");
                s.type = "text/javascript";
                s.src = "js2.js";
                s.innerHTML = null;
                s.id = "widget";
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("output").appendChild(s);
        break;
        default:
        void(0);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: but it increse the no of script files in resources

Answer (score 2):

```
function getData(title){
    document.getElementById("widget").src= (title == "ro" || title == "-") ? "js1.js" : "js2.js";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do simply:

```
function getData(title) {
    switch(title) {
        case "ro":
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = '<script id="widget" type="text/javascript" src="js1.js" />';
            break;
        case "en":
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = '<script id="widget" type="text/javascript" src="js2.js" />';
            break;
        default:
            void(0);
    }
}
```