# Changing version numbers on window.reload()

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

If I had the following `<script>` tag in my code:

`<script src='http://your.site.com/js/big_script.js?version=1'></script>`

How can I get this version number to automatically update with each subsequent `window.reload()` action placed on that page?

`Page refreshes...`

`<script src='http://your.site.com/js/big_script.js?version=2'></script>`

`Page refreshes...`

`<script src='http://your.site.com/js/big_script.js?version=3'></script>`

and so on... through use of JavaScript only?

I know `localStorage` would come in handy here but implementing it within the `<script>` tag itself? Is there a way of doing this, or are there alternative ways it could be done?

In this case I'm only after JavaScript based solutions only as the application is pure HTML5/JavaScript/CSS3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to increment the counter if the user opens another browser tab to the same URL?

Comment: @MjrKusanagi This application will not be run in a standard browser. It will be run in kiosk mode with no access to a keyboard on a touchscreen interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, localStorage is likely the way to go. The downside of doing this client side is that you'll have to late bind your script tag. I would try:

```
var my_site_cntr = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('mySite.counter')||0);
my_site_cntr++;
localStorage.setItem('mySite.counter', my_site_cntr);
var scrptElem = document.createElement("script");
    scrptElem.type = "text/javascript";
    scrptElem.src = "http://your.site.com/js/big_script.js?version=" + my_site_cntr;
    scrptElem.innerHTML = null;
document.body.appendChild(scrptElem);
```

Sources:

- [dynamically change script src client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748269/dynamically-change-script-src-client-side)
- [Adding div element to body or document in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741006/adding-div-element-to-body-or-document-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for that... Will the new `<script>` element still append immediately after the `<body>` tag or will it go to the very end of the list of child elements under it and form a new child element there?

Comment: It will be appended to the body element because I used the selector `document.body`. You can append it to any other element you want by changing `document.body` to something like `document.getElementById('id')`. You can read more about this and and other JS DOM selectors here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp