# Change parameter value in script tag using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I am trying to change a value of a parameter using JS or jQuery. I have a url that looks like this:

```
www.exampleurl.com/somepage?foo=test
```

I already have the code for getting the value coming after foo which is:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var foo = getParameterByName('foo');
```

I now have a page where the HTML-Code looks like this:

```
<div class="bonus-button">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://t.tellja.eu/widget/button/PSIGn2?skin=194&t_mc=kwk&btn=rec_somecompany"></script>
</div>
```

What I want to do is replace `t_mc=kwk` with `t_mc=value.of.foo`. In this example it would mean

```
<div class="bonus-button">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://t.tellja.eu/widget/button/PSIGn2?skin=194&t_mc=test&btn=rec_somecompany"></script>
</div>
```

So far I have not found something I could really use or that works. Do you guys have any suggestions what I could use, e.g. replace didn't work.

Comment: Not sure changing the src of a `<script>` tag that has already run would do what you think it would do.  Looks like an XY problem where you want to load a different script.  Changing the url of eg an `<img>` tag would be trivial with your existing code.

Comment: A quick search gives this (there are probably others) for what appears to be your actual issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13748269/2181514

Comment: For the question as it stands, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6021027/2181514

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add or update a query string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/how-can-i-add-or-update-a-query-string-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelector` to get the script tag and using `getAttribute` get the `src` from the script. In the string obtained using `split` and `join` replace the value and set the src again using `setAttribute`

```js
var a = document.querySelector('.bonus-button > script').getAttribute('src')
document.querySelector('div > script').setAttribute('src', a.split('t_mc=kwk').join('t_mc=value.of.foo'))
```

```html
<div class="bonus-button">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://t.tellja.eu/widget/button/PSIGn2?skin=194&t_mc=kwk&btn=rec_somecompany"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work in your example but I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null. Why is that=
Edit: I have it now thanks a lot and thanks for explaining what you did :)

Comment: That might be because the querySelector was for generally a div and script inside it. I have made edits and now it will work for the given div only provided there is no other div with the same class. Also make sure that there is a script tag and also has an src attribute.

Comment: yeah that was my mistake :( thanks again you saved my day :)